# Why is the chat message not showing immediately

Tags: flask-socketio

I made a page with a websocket using Flask-socketio worked on joining and disconnecting rooms, and one of the important ones is the chat. it works, but not as it should, messages are shown only after the page is refreshed, although they should appear as they arrive

here is an excerpt of the code that is responsible for this processing

```
@app.route("/room/<nameRoom>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def join_room(nameRoom): # room page
    session["room"] = nameRoom
    if nameRoom in rooms:
        url = rooms[nameRoom]['url']
        return render_template('roomyutube.html', id=get_video_id(url), messages=rooms[nameRoom]["messages"])
    else:
        error = 'not_room'
        return render_template('error.html', error=error)


@socketio.on("connect")
def connect(auth):
    room = session.get("room")
    name = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.get_id()).first().username
    if not room or not name:
        return 404
    if room not in rooms:
        leave_room(room)
        return

    join_room(room)
    send({"name": name, "message": "has entered the room"}, to=room)
    rooms[room]['members'].append(User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.get_id()).first().username)
    print(rooms[room])
    print(f"{name} joined room {room}")

@socketio.on("disconnect")
def disconnect():
    room = session.get("room")
    name = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.get_id()).first().username
    leave_room(room)

    if room in rooms:
        rooms[room]['members'].remove(name)
        if len(rooms[room]["members"]) <= 0:
            del rooms[room]

    send({"name": name, "message": "has left the room"}, to=room)
    print(rooms[room])
    print(f"{name} has left the room {room}")


@socketio.on("message")
def message(data):
    room = session.get("room")
    name = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.get_id()).first().username
    if room not in rooms:
        return

    content = {
        "name": name,
        "message": data["data"]
    }
    send(content, to=room)
    rooms[room]["messages"].append(content)
    print(f"{name} said: {data['data']}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
```

The code of the page with js

```
<body>
<div id="video-container">
    <iframe width="800" height="450"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ id }}" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>

<div class="chat-input" id="messages"></div>
<input id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Введите сообщение" class="text-light"/>
<button type="button" name="send" id="send-btn" onClick="sendMessage()">
    --->
</button>
<script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"
      integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var socketio = io();

  const messages = document.getElementById("messages");

  const createMessage = (name, msg) => {
    const content = `
    <div class="text">
        <span>
            <strong>${name}</strong>: ${msg}
        </span>
    </div>
    `;
    messages.innerHTML += content;
  };

  socketio.on("message", (data) => {
    createMessage(data.name, data.message);
  });

  const sendMessage = () => {
    const message = document.getElementById("message");
    if (message.value == "") return;
    socketio.emit("message", { data: message.value });
    message.value = "";
  };



</script>

{% for msg in messages %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  createMessage("{{msg.name}}", "{{msg.message}}");

</script>
{% endfor %}

</body>
```